# How to add cell value to certain part in Formula Bar

Tags: excel

I have a formula that takes a value from a cell in different sheet.

```
='WEEK 42'!E12
```

Is it possible for 'WEEK 42' to be taken from cell value? Or even just a number 42 to be taken from cell value?

Comment: Try Google the use of INDIRECT function.

Answer (score 3):

Use INDIRECT and concatenate the address you are interested in using &

[image]

Note that if the specified sheet name includes spaces (or certain other characters) you'll need to enclose the name in `'` ie

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!A1")
```

might as well do this regardless, just in case

Comment: This does not let me take values from different sheets, only from the active one

Comment: @Marko it let's you take values from whichever sheet you specify in cell B1

Comment: Note that if the specified sheet name includes spaces (or certain other characters) you'll need to enclose the name in `'` ie `=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!A1")` - might as well do this regardless, just in case